# Google Calendar API Dependencies are not working

Tags: java, api, jar, dependencies, google-calendar-api

I have been trying for the past day to get at least google's sample code working. Every single of their sample code have dependencies issues or errors within the code (even they have stated in quick start thats a copy/pasta code to test the api - never works). I have installed all of the dependencies, I pointed the jar file to the missing imports, but no success in that..

Can anyone tell me where is the problem when my jar is in dependencies but it never finds it?

I wish they had a normal way of taking json data - via url, but they disabled this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using this for an Android App or just a Desktop application?

Comment: i was using for java one. Now it works as I downloaded their sample code as a project, but once I do it in another project, it messes it out

Comment: so this is non-android?

Comment: They have 2 separate examples. For android and for java. I used for java as I have nothing to do with the android here. But even in java examples they have 'build.gradle' instructions which I have no idea whats that all about